# Manage Multiple domain and single admin

Tags: typo3

I want to Manage 2 website within a single admin. Below is my page structure,

purchase page  (set as root page)

- contact page
- about page

Marketing page (set as root page)

- strategy page
- partner page

Now i have read the concept of multi domain from https://wiki.typo3.org/Multidomain  and created domain record for purchase page and Marketing pag,

I am using the introduction package for my purchase page site.
and for Marketing page i have writed script like

```
config.typolinkCheckRootline = 1
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEMPLATE
page.10.template = FILE
page.10.template.file = fileadmin/template/index.html
page.shortcutIcon = fileadmin/template/favicon.ico
page.stylesheet = fileadmin/template/style.css
```

Now I am getting page not found when trying marketing.com (set in domain record for Marketing page )

Please help some one so I can go ahead,

Divyang

Comment: It should normally work when your domain records are set up correctly. These are the settings I would double-check:
1. Domain records are not disabled and no redirect is set. 2. Only the domain name is entered (marketing.com) not the full URL (h**p://marketing.com/) 3. Use as root page is enabled (globe icon on the top level page) 4. The root page is not an invalid shortcut.

Comment: Does "page not found" generated by TYPO3 or by server itself? In latter case this may mean, that your domain points to not correct document root.